# Highchart's stacked bars switching places

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

I have to create a chart with stacked bars, and I reached a problem: when I disable a particular serie (by clicking it in the legend), the stacks on the right change places with the ones on the left.

As a demo means more than a long explanation, there is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/69gep9rt/

```
To reproduce the switch, simply click on "Banana (Male)" in the legend.
```

I have no idea what causes this behavior, and since the Y-Axis are fixed, I need to keep males on the left and females on the right.

A solution and/or an explanation could be very helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the issue with your code is linked to x axis' indexes.
You should group the males and the females under the same x index. For example, all males with index equals to 0 and all females equals to 1.
Another solution is to use a growing index with all males first and then all the females.

```
  series: [
  {
     name: "Banana (Male)",
     data: [29,13,16,54,21,2],
     stack: "Male",
     id: "Banana",
     code: "BAN",
     yAxis: 0,
     index: 0,  // all Male have index = 0
     legendIndex: 2,
     color: "rgba(0,169,224,1)"
  },
  {
     name: "Banana (Female)",
     data: [1305,680,720,2520,945,90],
     stack: "Female",
     id: "Banana",
     code: "BAN",
     yAxis: 1,
     index: 1,  // all Female have index = 1
     legendIndex: 2,
     color: "rgba(0,169,224,0.8)"
  },
  {
     name: "Apple (Male)",
     data: [266,235,150,215,213,17],
     stack: "Male",
     id: "Apple",
     code: "APL",
     yAxis: 0,
     index: 0,
     legendIndex: 1,
     color: "rgba(206,0,88,1)"
  },
  {
     name: "Apple (Female)",
     data: [14045,11690,7280,10667.64,10345,765],
     stack: "Female",
     id: "Apple",
     code: "APL",
     yAxis: 1,
     index: 1,
     legendIndex: 1,
     color: "rgba(206,0,88,0.8)"
  },
  {
     name: "Tomato (Male)",
     data: [11293,10300,7975,10703,10934,868],
     stack: "Male",
     id: "Tomato",
     code: "TOM",
     yAxis: 0,
     index: 0,
     legendIndex: 0,
     color: "rgba(130,70,175,1)"
  },
  {
     name: "Tomato (Female)",
     data: [221800,200210,156990,209080,211945,15675],
     stack: "Female",
     id: "Tomato",
     code: "TOM",
     yAxis: 1,
     index: 1,
     legendIndex: 0,
     color: "rgba(130,70,175,0.8)"
  }
]
```

Here the jsFiddle for solution one: http://jsfiddle.net/69gep9rt/2/

Ciao 
Davide